# Mocking Request in Laravel 5.1 for (actual) Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, laravel-5, tdd, laravel-5.1

First of all, I'm aware the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#mocking) states:

> Note: You should not mock the Request facade. Instead, pass the input you desire into the HTTP helper methods such as call and post when running your test.

**But** those kind of tests are more like *integration or functional* since even though you're testing a **controller** (the `SUT`), you're not decoupling it from it's dependencies (`Request` and others, more on this later).

So what I'm doing, in order to do the correct `TDD` loop, is mocking the `Repository`, `Response` and `Request` (which I have problems with).

My test look like this:

```php
public function test__it_shows_a_list_of_categories() {
    $categories = [];
    $this->repositoryMock->shouldReceive('getAll')
        ->withNoArgs()
        ->once()
        ->andReturn($categories);
    Response::shouldReceive('view')
        ->once()
        ->with('categories.admin.index')
        ->andReturnSelf();
    Response::shouldReceive('with')
        ->once()
        ->with('categories', $categories)
        ->andReturnSelf();

    $this->sut->index();

    // Assertions as mock expectations
}
```

This works perfectly fine, and they follow the *Arrange, Act, Assert* style.

The problem is with `Request`, like the following:

```php
public function test__it_stores_a_category() {
    Redirect::shouldReceive('route')
        ->once()
        ->with('categories.admin.index')
        ->andReturnSelf();

    Request::shouldReceive('only')
        ->once()
        ->with('name')
        ->andReturn(['name' => 'foo']);

    $this->repositoryMock->shouldReceive('create')
        ->once()
        ->with(['name' => 'foo']);

    // Laravel facades wont expose Mockery#getMock() so this is a hackz
    // in order to pass mocked dependency to the controller's method
    $this->sut->store(Request::getFacadeRoot());

    // Assertions as mock expectations
}
```

As you can see I have mocked `Request::only('name')` call. But when I run `$ phpunit` I get the following error:

```php
BadMethodCallException: Method Mockery_3_Illuminate_Http_Request::setUserResolver() does not exist on this mock object
```

Since I'm not calling directly `setUserResolver()` from my controller, that means it is called directly by the implementation of `Request`. But why? I mocked the method call, it shouldn't be calling any dependency.

What am I doing wrong here, why am I getting this error message?

PS: As a bonus, am I looking it the wrong way by forcing TDD with Unit Tests on Laravel framework, as it seems the documentation is  oriented to integration testing by coupling interaction between dependencies and SUT with `$this->call()`?

Comment: Ran into this today. Related: https://twitter.com/laravelphp/status/556568018864459776

Comment: Simpler option: If your function under test takes a `Request` argument, and a plain "real route path" Request is all you need, then: **you don't need to _mock_ a Request, you can just _create_ a Request from the route** and pass it, like this: `$myRequest = Request::create('/path/that/I_want', 'GET'); $this->assertTrue(functionUnderTest($myRequest));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unit testing a controller when using Laravel doesn't seem like a great idea. I wouldn't be concerned with the individual methods that are being called on the Request, Response and maybe even the repository classes, given the context of a Controller.

Furthermore, unit testing a controller belonging to a framework because you want to decouple the test sut from its dependencies doesn't make sense, as you can only use that controller in that framework with those given dependencies.

As the request, response and other classes are all fully tested (either via the underlying Symfony class, or by Laravel itself), as a developer I'd concern myself only with testing the code I own.

I'd write an acceptance test.

```php
<?php

use App\User;
use App\Page;
use App\Template;
use App\PageType;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class CategoryControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;

    /** @test */
    public function test__it_shows_a_paginated_list_of_categories()
    {
        // Arrange
        $categories = factory(Category::class, 30)->create();

        // Act
        $this->visit('/categories')

        // Assert
            ->see('Total categories: 30')
            // Additional assertions to verify the right categories can be seen may be a useful additional test
            ->seePageIs('/categories')
            ->click('Next')
            ->seePageIs('/categories?page=2')
            ->click('Previous')
            ->seePageIs('/categories?page=1');
    }

}
```

Because this test uses the `DatabaseTransactions` trait, it's easy to perform the arrange part of the process, which almost allows you to read this as a pseudo-unit test (but that's a slight stretch of the imagination).

Most importantly, this test verifies that my expectations are met. My test is called `test_it_shows_a_paginated_list_of_categories` and my version of the test does exactly that. I feel the unit test route only asserts that a bunch of methods are called, but doesn't ever verify that I'm showing a list of the given categories on a page.

Comment: My personal use case is that I've created a helper function that uses the request()->root() function to determine a result. e.g. when the URL is this, do that. So, I want to test my helper function by mocking request()->root() to return specific values... but I can't. Is there no other way to properly mock the request() facade?

Comment: I think if you're having to mock the Facade, there's an opportunity for refactoring. For your helper function, I'd expect it to accept a string parameter ```$url```. That way you can easily unit test your helper function using any parameter you want to pass.

Answer (score 3):

You will always run into problems trying to properly unit test controllers. I recommend acceptance testing them with something like [Codeception](http://codeception.com/). Using acceptance tests you can ensure your controllers/views are handling any data appropriately.

Comment: Yes, controllers are like the "glue" of your application. They combine many of your services into actions. The point of unit testing is to test units of code in isolation. Controllers are not meant to be a small unit, they tie many things together. It's a much better use case for an acceptance or functional test.

Comment: The problem is not only with controllers. Today I tried a functional test for custom repository trait which invloves paginating the results through Laravel's paginator. It turned out, that Laravel's paginate() method reads page number directly from Request->input(), so I have to mock it somehow to return correct page number, as required by my test.

Comment: @JustAMartin I ran into the exact same situation today, My repository's `getPageOfDealers(Request $request)` receive a Request object then filter and paginate the result accordingly. But to test this I have to mock Request.

Comment: As a workaround for my situation I used Request::replace method to inject pagination parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I tried mocking the Request for my tests too with no success.
Here is how I test if item is saved:

```
public function test__it_stores_a_category() {
    $this->action(
            'POST',
            'CategoryController@store',
            [],
            [
                'name' => 'foo',
            ]
        );

    $this->assertRedirectedTo('categories/admin/index');

    $this->seeInDatabase('categories', ['name' => 'foo']);
}
```

Hope it is of some help